# Read fm file in netCobol Fujitsu

Tags: cobol, netcobol

I have multiple *.fm files. if I open some file in notepad, in the header I can see "rmkf"

I only want open this file.

I tried to connect with the jdbc driver but it says HXTT need the file data structure (FD) have also tested with an application developed in Delphy that extracts some data but not all

I do not know what else to investigate

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the extension, is this a framemaker file?

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/fm